# Unable to send mail when trying to get mail recipient from a file outside the script in the same dir

Tags: shell, email, unix

I use the code below and it's working fine.

```
dl=xyz@somebody.com

mail -t $dl << EOM
  Subject: Report Status $(date)
  Content-Type: text/html
  mail text
EOM
```

However, when I try to get the mail id from file dl.txt, no mail is sent.

```
dl='/script/user/dl.txt'

mail -t $(echo cat $dl) << EOM
  subject: Report Status $(date)
  content-Type: text/html
  mail text
EOM
```

Note: text file contains mail ids.

Comment: please ignore the typos.(eg: $dl in caps etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to run

```
dl='/script/user/dl.txt'
echo cat $dl
```

The output will be

```
cat /script/user/dl.txt
```

Remove **echo** or better change code like this

```
to=$(cat '/script/user/dl.txt')

mail -t $to << EOM
  Subject: Report Status $(date)
  Content-Type: text/html
  mail text
EOM
```